# Runtime Error 1004 - Stopped at "End With" by debugger

Tags: debugging, runtime

Alright, I think it would be a bit tough to explain what I'm trying to do, but debugger is jamming on "End With" and just couldn't go on. I just can't figure out what's wrong. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
Private Sub AddHyperlinks()
    Dim i As Integer
        For i = 3 To 5
                If Cells(i, 1).Value = vbNullString Then
                    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
                        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range(Cells(i, 2)), _
                        Address:="C:\Dropbox\DASC\DASC_v1.00\MIBD\MIB00" & Range(Cells(i, 4)).Value & ".xlsm", _
                        ScreenTip:="", _
                        TextToDisplay:="Info"
                    End With
                End If
        Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Even if it's tough, try explaining it. Otherwise we don't know what an answer could look like.

Comment: What are the values in `i,2`  and `i,4`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. The main cause for runtime error was this command:

```
Range(Cells(i, 2)).Value
```

and all other

```
Range(Cells(#, #))
```

Here is the redefined code working correctly:

```
Private Sub AddHyperlinks()
    Dim i As Integer
        For i = 3 To 5
                If Cells(i, 1).Value = vbNullString Then
                    With Worksheets("Sheet2")
                        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(i, 1), _
                        Address:="C:\Dropbox\DASC\DASC_v1.00\MIBD\MIB\MIB00" & Cells(i, 4).Value & ".xlsm", _
                        ScreenTip:="Info", _
                        TextToDisplay:="Info"
                    End With
                End If
        Next i
End Sub
```

I suppose this problem has already been answered somewhere else on StackOverflow, but I wasn't even able to find out what the problem was. +1 to my VBA skills and a handy thing to remember for the newbies as I am :) thanks all